# How to make a for loop with two indexes?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-for-loop

Dear StackOverflow users,

I am struggling to implement a for loop. I have a dataframe with a column Time (YMD-HMS format) and another column with particulate matter data. Furthermore, I have a dataframe with start and stop moments;

```
#TIMEPOINTS log

start <- c(ymd_hms("2020-03-06 19:43:00",
                   "2020-03-06 19:47:00",
                   "2020-03-06 19:53:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:00:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:13:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:22:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:32:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:36:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:42:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:45:00",
                   "2020-03-06 20:49:00",
                   "2020-03-06 21:01:00",
                   "2020-03-06 21:04:00",
                   "2020-03-06 21:06:00",
                   "2020-03-06 21:09:00",
                   "2020-03-06 21:12:00"))

end <- c(ymd_hms("2020-03-06 19:46:00",
                 "2020-03-06 19:49:00",
                 "2020-03-06 19:55:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:02:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:15:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:24:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:34:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:38:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:44:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:47:00",
                 "2020-03-06 20:51:00",
                 "2020-03-06 21:03:00",
                 "2020-03-06 21:06:00",
                 "2020-03-06 21:08:00",
                 "2020-03-06 21:11:00",
                 "2020-03-06 21:14:00"))

df <- data.frame(start, end)
```

I wish to create a new dataframe with all datapoints without these specific timepoints, like this; (but than using a forloop, iterating over the various starting and end points).

```
dat2 <- dat %>% .[.[["Time"]] >= df$start[1],] %>%
    .[.[["Time"]] <= df$end[1],]
```

I know this can be done using a for loop and I tried to figure it out for my case, but I'm a bit lost..

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The solution you have is perfectly fine (kind of …), and in fact vastly superior than a `for` loop would be. What’s your reason for wanting to use a `for` loop here? Or is the purpose to exclude *all* times falling into the ranges in your `df`?

Comment: Sorry, apparently my question was not clear enough. Indeed, I would like to exclude all the times falling into these ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, I’d clean up your current code slightly:

```
dat2 <- dat %>% .[.$Time >= df$start[1] && .$Time <= df$end[1],]
```

By using `&&`, you’ve reduced two subset operations into one. And using `$…` reduces clutter compared to `[["…"]]` in this case.

Next, I suggest extracting this condition into a function (in fact that function already exists in the ‘dplyr’ package: [`between`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/between.html)). This allows us to write the code as

```
dat2 <- dat %>% filter(between(Time, df$start[1], df$end[1]))
```

Now we want to vectorise this to check for overlap with *any* interval:

```
dat2 <- dat %>% filter(between_any(Time, df$start, df$end))
```

Now we need to write that `between_any` function. Let’s start by implementing it for a *single* query value:

```
between_any1 = function (x, left, right) {
    any(x >= left & x <=  right)
}
```

Note the use of `&` here, instead of `&&`; this is because we *vectorised* over `left` and `right`, and `&` is the vectorised version of `&&`. That is, `4 >= (1 : 3) & 4 <= (3 : 5)` results in `c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)`.

Now we need to make this work when `x` is a vector. We could use the base R function `Vectorize` but I generally find it better to do it manually:

```
between_any = function (x, left, right) {
    map_lgl(x, ~ any(.x >= left & .x <= right))
}
```

This uses ‘purrr’, but we could just as well have used `lapply` or `vapply`.

Oh, and it sounds like you wanted to *filter out* times falling into the ranges in your `df`, so you need to invert the condition for `filter`:

```
dat2 <- dat %>% filter(! between_any(Time, df$from, df$to))
```